# Get Rotation Parameter from homogeneous transformation calculated by SVD

Tags: rotation, eigen, angle, homogenous-transformation

I got a homogeneous transformation by using eigen::umeyama.
According to the documentation
(http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html)
this transformation consists of a rotation, where the scaling is already multiplied to, and a translation. I changed the eigen::umeyama code in a way, that I get the scaling (c) also returned seperately.

Now I want to compare the transformation parameters found bei eigen::umeyama seperately. Since I get the scaling (c) and have easy access to the translation vector (t), only the ratation (R) is not easy to handle.

Since R is computed by SVD, I have no idea how it is constructed and how to access the rotation parameters.

Is there a way to calculate the rotation angles of the different axes from R? Or is there any way to compare the rotation matrix (or its parameters) directly to others, found by using different data sets?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem. Do you want to convert the rotation matrix to Euler angles? (And if yes, why?). If you want to check if two rotation matrices are close, just compute the Frobenious norm of the difference.

Comment: I would like to visualize how the rotation is affected by influences like distance in what the point sets are obtained. Maybe I could also alter the angle of a specific axis if I detect some issues with the calculated angles.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment made it even more vague to me what you actually intent to do ...

Comment: Basicly, I just want to get the rotation parameters (angle per axis) from the rotation matrix returned by eigen::umeyama (which is based on SVD).

Comment: To get Euler angles from a rotation matrix, you can use [`eulerAngles`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__Geometry__Module.html#gac3d90b12b21e1aaa2a9de9b0e45e6b7c) or use the (unsupported) [`EulerAngles` module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__EulerAngles__Module.html)